# rails 3 nested routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

my routes.rb

```
TerritoryManagement::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :addresses
    resources :territories, :shallow => true do
  resources :addresses
  end
end
```

rake routes says

```
$ rake routes
        addresses GET    /addresses(.:format)
{:action=>"index", :controller=>"addresses"}
                  POST   /addresses(.:format)
{:action=>"create", :controller=>"addresses"}
      new_address GET    /addresses/new(.:format)
{:action=>"new", :controller=>"addresses"}
     edit_address GET    /addresses/:id/edit(.:format)
{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"addresses"}
          address GET    /addresses/:id(.:format)
{:action=>"show", :controller=>"addresses"}
                  PUT    /addresses/:id(.:format)
{:action=>"update", :controller=>"addresses"}
                  DELETE /addresses/:id(.:format)
{:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"addresses"}
  territory_addresses GET    /territories/:territory_id/addresses(.:format)
{:action=>"index", :controller=>"addresses"}
                  POST   /territories/:territory_id/addresses(.:format)
{:action=>"create", :controller=>"addresses"}
new_territory_address GET    /territories/:territory_id/addresses/new(.:format)
{:action=>"new", :controller=>"addresses"}
                  GET    /addresses/:id/edit(.:format)
{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"addresses"}
                  GET    /addresses/:id(.:format)
{:action=>"show", :controller=>"addresses"}
                  PUT    /addresses/:id(.:format)
{:action=>"update", :controller=>"addresses"}
                  DELETE /addresses/:id(.:format)
{:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"addresses"}
      territories GET    /territories(.:format)
{:action=>"index", :controller=>"territories"}
                  POST   /territories(.:format)
{:action=>"create", :controller=>"territories"}
    new_territory GET    /territories/new(.:format)
{:action=>"new", :controller=>"territories"}
   edit_territory GET    /territories/:id/edit(.:format)
{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"territories"}
        territory GET    /territories/:id(.:format)
{:action=>"show", :controller=>"territories"}
                  PUT    /territories/:id(.:format)
{:action=>"update", :controller=>"territories"}
                  DELETE /territories/:id(.:format)
{:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"territories"}
```

in my list of territories I have the link

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', new_territory_address_path %></td>
```

I get the error

No route matches {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"new"}
Extracted source (around line #14):

```
11: <% @territories.each do |territory| %>
12:   <tr>
13:     <td><%= territory.name %></td>
14:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', new_territory_address_path %></td>
15:     <td><%= link_to 'Delete', territory, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
16:   </tr> 
17: <% end %>
```

What am I missing?

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing it a territory_id? Notice how it's included in the full route.

```
new_territory_address_path(:territory_id => territory.id)
```

Comment: You could even just pass the territory object itself, Rails will know what you mean: `new_territory_address_path(territory)`

Comment: ok, thanks and why isn't this one working? territory_path(:territory_id => territory.id)

Comment: I have one more problem in this context. In my territory show view I'm rendering an address form, to be able to add addresses to a specific territory. So now with territory_path(territory) working it says ActionController::RoutingError in Territories#show No route matches {:controller=>"addresses"} and says it doesn't like this beginning of the partial <%= form_for @address do |f| %> What's wrong with that?